# Diagram to model database entries

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, erd

Do you know a diagram to show the entries of an database? I guess something like the object diagram in UML. I know there is the entity-relationship model but it does not show the existing entries of the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "entries of a database"?  The ERD can be the Logical or Physical model of the database.  The immediate difference is that the Logical model won't display foreign key columns - you have to read the crows feet/etc to know what foreign keys will exist.

Comment: You probably don't want UML for a database diagram. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model

Comment: The variation of the e-r diagram that is posted by Yacoder shows what I need. I do not want to show thousands of entries. I just want to show some example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's pretty much uncommon to show database entries in a diagram, because there are usually way too many of them.

And actually, it can be a business-specific diagram, you can think of any DB-based application as a form of such "diagram", showing database entries in a way comfortable to the user.

Another way of making up such diagram is to use some variation of the E-R diagram, but show the data instead of the schema, like in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_model).

[image: Show the data instead of the schema]

Answer (score 0):

Yacoder mentioned ER diagrams.  That's a good place to start.  ER diagrams are simpler than UML diagrams.  I've seen ER diagrams with well over a hundred boxes,  and way more lines between boxes.  The paper covers an entire wall.

In case you think this is way too complicated, it still easier to understand a hundred tables than a hundred thousand lines of code.